# Strip card errors not showing if logged out

Tags: stripe, devdemon-subscriptions

Using Devdemon's Subscription system, we have a sign up and card form all on one page. If I enter the correct details for the account and card details when I am logged out (which most new sign ups will be) then it logs the user in and creates the subscription all OK.

If I make a mistake in the card details, it returns me to this page with no error showing. But the user is still registered and logged in.

If I make the same incorrect card submission now I am logged in, I get the Stripe error that the card number is wrong.

So it seems that the Stripe error is not showing if the user is originally not logged in when registering (even though they are still registered when entering the wrong card details).

Here is our template code

Thanks

```
{embed="_inc/.header" sidebar="off"}

    {if segment_3 == ""}

    <h2>You are not subscribed to any plan. Please choose a plan...</h2>

    {exp:subs:plans}

    <a href="/{segment_1}/{segment_2}/{subs:handle}">{subs:label}</a><br/>

    {/exp:subs:plans}

    {/if}



    {if segment_3 != ""}

        {!-- http://www.devdemon.com/documentation/tag/subs-subscribe/ --}

        {exp:subs:subscribe
            register_member="yes"
            plan="{segment_3}"
            payment_method="stripe"
            return="/members/subscription/%SUBS_HASH%"
        }


        <input type="hidden" name="card_token" class="stripe_token">

        <div class="stripe_error"></div>


        <div class="uniform">

            {if subs:no_results}
            {redirect="/{segment_1}/{segment_2}"}
            {/if}


            <h1>Subscribe to: {subs:plan:label}</h1>

            <p>
                Every <strong>{subs:plan:recurring_interval_count} {subs:plan:recurring_interval}</strong> {subs:plan:recurring_amount} {subs:plan:currency}
            </p>

            <p>Add Coupon: <em>(Discount will be applied at checkout)</em></p>
            <p><input type="text" name="coupon" value="{subs:coupon}"></p>

            {if subs:total_errors}
            <ul class="message error">
                {subs:form_errors}
                <li>{subs:error}</li>
                {/subs:form_errors}
            </ul>
            {/if}


            {if logged_out}
            <h3>Account Details</h3>

            <p>
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" value="">
            </p>

            <p>
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" value="">
            </p>

            <p>
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" value="">
            </p>

            <p>
                <label>Password Confirm</label>
                <input type="password" name="password_confirm" value="">
            </p>
            {/if}


            {if logged_in}
            {exp:member:custom_profile_data}
            <div class="col-wrap twelvecol">

                <div class="col twelvecol">
                    <h2>Your Details</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol"></div>

                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol clear">
                    <label for="m_field_id_1">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_1" class="form-control" value="{first_name}">
                </div>

                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_2">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_2" class="form-control" value="{last_name}">
                </div>
                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_10">Phone Number</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_10" class="form-control" value="{telephone}">
                </div>

                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_21">School Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_21" class="form-control" value="{school_name}">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-wrap twelvecol">&nbsp;</div>

            <div class="col-wrap twelvecol">

                <div class="col twelvecol">
                    <h2>Billing Address</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_3">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_3" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_4">Address Line 2</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_4" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_5">City</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_5" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_6">County</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_6" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_8">Country</label>
                    {exp:cartthrob:country_select name="m_field_id_8" selected="GBR"}
                </div>
                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_7">Postcode</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_7" class="form-control">
                </div>

            </div>
            {/exp:member:custom_profile_data} 
            {/if}



            {if logged_out}
            <div class="col-wrap twelvecol">

                <div class="col twelvecol">
                    <h2>Your Details</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol"></div>

                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol clear">
                    <label for="m_field_id_1">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_1" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_2">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_2" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_10">Phone Number</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_10" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_21">School Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_21" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-wrap twelvecol">&nbsp;</div>

            <div class="col-wrap twelvecol">

                <div class="col twelvecol">
                    <h2>Billing Address</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_3">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_3" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_4">Address Line 2</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_4" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_5">City</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_5" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_6">County</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_6" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_8">Country</label>
                    {exp:cartthrob:country_select name="m_field_id_8" selected="GBR"}
                </div>
                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_7">Postcode</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_7" class="form-control">
                </div>

            </div>
            {/if}





            <div class="col-wrap twelvecol">&nbsp;</div>


            {if "{subs:has_cards}" == 'yes'}

            <div class="col twelvecol">
                <h2>Pay with Credit Card</h2>
            </div>


            {exp:subs:cards prefix="card"}

            <div class="cardslist col-wrap twelvecol">

                <div class="col twelvecol cards-box">
                    <input name="card_hash" value="{card:hash}" type="radio" class="card_hash"> {card:brand} ending in {card:last4} {card:name_on_card} {card:exp_month}/{card:exp_year}
                </div>

            </div>


                <div class="cardstoggler col twelvecol">
                    <input name="card_hash" value="" type="radio" class="card_hash"> 
                    <strong>Add a new card</strong> <i>saves on submission below</i>
                </div>

            {/exp:subs:cards}

            {/if}






            <div class="col-wrap twelvecol cardnew">

                <div class="col twelvecol">
                    <h2>Payment Details</h2>
                </div>


                <div class="col twelvecol">
                    <label>Credit Card Number</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="card_number" value="{subs:card_number}" class="form-control stripe_number" data-stripe="number">
                </div>

                <div class="col twelvecol">
                    <label>Name on card</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="card_name" value="{subs:card_name}" class="form-control stripe_name" data-stripe="name">
                </div>

                <div class="col twelvecol">
                    <label for="card_number">Expires</label><br/>
                    <select name="card_exp_month" class="form-control stripe_exp_month free" data-stripe="exp_month">{subs:month_options}</select>

                    <select name="card_exp_year" class="form-control stripe_exp_year free" data-stripe="exp_year">{subs:year_options}</select>
                </div>

                <div class="col twelvecol">
                    <label>Security Code</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="card_cvc" value="{subs:card_cvc}" class="form-control stripe_cvc" data-stripe="cvc" size="5">
                </div>

            </div>


            <div class="col-wrap twelvecol">&nbsp;</div>

            {if logged_in}
            {exp:member:custom_profile_data} 
            <div class="col-wrap twelvecol">

                <div class="col twelvecol">
                    <h2>Shipping Details</h2>
                </div>


                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_11">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_11" class="form-control" value="{shipping_first_name}">
                </div>

                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_12">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_12" class="form-control" value="{shipping_last_name}">
                </div>

                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_13">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_13" class="form-control" value="{shipping_address}">
                </div>
                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_14">Address Line 2</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_14" class="form-control" value="{shipping_address2}">
                </div>
                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_15">City</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_15" class="form-control" value="{shipping_city}">
                </div>
                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_16">County</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_16" class="form-control" value="{shipping_county}">
                </div>
                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_18">Country</label>
                    {exp:cartthrob:country_select name="m_field_id_18" {if country_code!=""}selected="{country_code}"{/if}{if country_code==""}selected="GBR"{/if}}
                </div>
                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_17">Postcode</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_17" class="form-control" value="{shipping_postcode}">
                </div>

            </div>
            {/exp:member:custom_profile_data} 
            {/if}


            {if logged_out}
            <div class="col-wrap twelvecol">

                <div class="col twelvecol">
                    <h2>Shipping Details</h2>
                </div>


                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_11">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_11" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_12">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_12" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_13">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_13" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_14">Address Line 2</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_14" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_15">City</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_15" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_16">County</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_16" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_18">Country</label>
                    {exp:cartthrob:country_select name="m_field_id_18" selected="GBR"}
                </div>
                <div class="col sixcol land-twelvecol">
                    <label for="m_field_id_17">Postcode</label>
                    <input type="text" name="m_field_id_17" class="form-control">
                </div>

            </div>
            {/if}




            <div class="col-wrap twelvecol">&nbsp;</div>










            <p>
                <button type="submit" class="stripe_submit">Subscribe</button>
            </p>

        </div>

        {/exp:subs:subscribe}

    {/if}

{embed="_inc/.footer" sidebar="off"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we were missing the stripe key field. Adding this in and now it works OK. Strangely it worked previously without this, if the card details were correct, which is why we were confused.

```
{if subs:test_mode == 'yes'}<input type="hidden" class="stripe_public_key" value="YOUR_TEST_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY">{/if}
{if subs:test_mode == 'no'}<input type="hidden" class="stripe_public_key" value="YOUR_LIVE_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY">{/if}
<input type="hidden" name="card_token" class="stripe_token">
```